# Populating jks file with keys from 509 certificates

Tags: ssl-certificate, storage, public-key, convert, keytool

Does anyone have detailed, step by step, instructions for extracting encryption keys from 509 certificates, and then storing them inside an encrypted jks file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java VM installation includes a tool for performing this exact type of work - on windows systems it is called keytool.exe.

Depending no the situation, there may be multiple steps to the process. For many cases, the two steps in this example will do:

1. Create a key store. A command similar to the following will create the keystore:
   keytool -genkey -alias  -keystore keystore.jks
2. Import the signed certificate + private key into the keystore. The following command will do the trick:

keytool -import -keystore keystore.jks -file .crt

The certificate can be provided in a number of different formats. Full documentation is available on Sun's site, here:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html